# 1960s F&SF short story - 'Please let not be a Lovecraftian Universe'

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am almost positive this story appeared in a 1960s issue of F&SF.
Items are being pilfered from a large department store and a night watchman (an SF fan) is hired to prevent it. Late at night he is confronted by a large, blob-like alien creature. (There may have been two, I can't remember.) He is chased into a basement storeroom and slams the door shut. As the aliens try to force their way in he finds wooden chocks from somewhere and jams them under the door; the aliens kick them away again. As he replaces them he prays that he does not live in an H.P. Lovecraft-like universe and that the aliens are not the typical evil Lovecraftian creatures. (I had only recently read my first Lovecraft story  -'The Color Out Of Space' - and was impressed by the author's use of his name.)  As it turns out, the aliens are friendly and were just taking items necessary to repair their ship.

Comment: Worrh remembering that authors like August Derleth were publishing Cthulhu stories in the 50s and 60s; Lovecraft wasn't that obscure in the period this was published.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

["Counter Security"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63760), a novelette by [James White](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_White_%28author%29), first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, February 1963](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61086), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v024n02_1963-02_PDF/page/n9/mode/1up).

> The smaller alien behind him had amused itself by pulling the arms off dolls. The second one . . . Tully wondered sickly what it would feel like to have his arms and leg pulled off, his nose mutilated and his eye . . . He tried desperately not to think about it, tried to think about good, civilised aliens, but his mind kept turning back to the other sort. The sort that Lovecraft used to write about.
>
> According to Lovecraft the whole of Time and Space was peopled with cruel, debased, unspeakably foul entities, beings as cold and malignant and uncaring as the interstellar wastes in which they dwelt. Humanity with its concern over Right and Wrong inhabited a single dust-mote, unknown and unknowing, in a continuum that was one vast, blasphemous obscenity. Tully had not liked Lovecraft's ideas, but they had been written up so well that they had stuck in his mind despite this. And Lovecraft's aliens were the type who *would* pull another living, intelligent creature apart with less feeling than an unthinking boy would pull the legs off a fly . . .
>
> Two more wedges jerked from under the door, and Tully couldn't move to replace them. All he could do was shake. His mind seemed to be a tight, hard ball of panic. He was beginning to realise that it was an *alien* at the other side of the door, a being whose civilisation and philosophy and thought processes were such that there might be no common ground between them. And even if understanding was possible, he had spoiled any chance he had ever had of gaining it by closing the door.

The story has a happy ending, as the aliens turn out not to be Lovecraftian horrors:

> Later that morning, as he tidied up the corridor and Toy department after the aliens had gone underground for the day, Tully thought that it had been obvious from the very start that a child had been responsible for the doll business. While its parent had been up in Hardware searching for the proper tools, Junior had grown bored. It had wanted to play with a dolly, but all the dollies in the Toy department were the wrong shape. So it had chosen one that was the nearest in colour and pulled off the arms and a leg to give it a more 'human' shape. Twisting out its nose and hair to resemble the five tentacles and cone-like proboscis and removing the surplus eye had been further attempts towards that end. Looked at objectively, the mutilated dolls did look a little like the aliens. But not much, because the small alien had never thought enough of them to bring them back into the ship.

Comment: For some reason, I remembered this as being by Harry Harrison.

Comment: user14111: This is the story - thanks very much! I looked through the contents of EVERY ISSUE of of the 1960s F&SF on ISFDB with no luck. I even remember seeing this story, but I did not associate the title with the plot. Thanks again.

Comment: @LeeEckhardt I looked through the etexts at the Internet Archive and searched for the word Lovecraft. There were a lot of false positives from book reviews, and then this.

Comment: I would never have thought of that. I appreciate the effort.